# Need help writing this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, northwind

Using the Logical operators: AND, OR, write a query that returns the orders placed in July 1996
by Nancy Davolio, Janet Leverling, and Steven Buchanan. List the order id, employee id, and
the order date. Order the result set by the employeeID. Northwind Database

Comment: this sounds more like a demand than a question lol

Comment: You need to provide some information about your tables and what have you tried so far. Dont have a slightest clue who are these people :)

Comment: What's the part causing you difficulty?

Comment: They are made up names. I wrote the query but it is not turning up any results except the column names. The rest of the data is blank.

Comment: @Rnofx5 When you post your question you should also post your attempt, and some information about your tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT O.OrderID
      ,E.EmployeeID
      ,O.OrderDate 
FROM dbo.Orders O INNER JOIN dbo.Employees E
ON O.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
WHERE YEAR(O.OrderDate) = 1996
 AND  MONTH(O.OrderDate)= 7
 AND E.FirstName IN ('Nancy','Janet', 'Steven')
```

**Using strictly AND and OR Operator**

```
SELECT O.OrderID
      ,E.EmployeeID
      ,O.OrderDate 
FROM dbo.Orders O INNER JOIN dbo.Employees E
ON O.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
WHERE YEAR(O.OrderDate) = 1996
 AND  MONTH(O.OrderDate)= 7
 AND 
     (   E.FirstName = 'Nancy'
      OR E.FirstName = 'Janet'
      OR E.FirstName =  'Steven'
     )
```

Comment: It's nice to see you can get your blatant homework done for free by 10K+ users here